# Comparing the grow rate of two functions with discrete domain

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics, rate-of-convergence

Consider all the possible ways to put $\{0,1\}$ in $m\in \mathbb{N}$ places. E.g., if $m=3$, then the number of possibilities is $8$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Fix any $j\in \{0,2,...,m\}$. I am interested in the number of rows of the matrix above giving $j$ as sum. 
E.g., for $j=2$, I have $3$ rows (second, third, fourth).

I found that this number can be calculated as

$$
\frac{m!}{j!(m-j)!}
$$

For any fixed value of $m$, the function $f_m$ such that $j\in \{0,1,...,m\}\mapsto f(j)\equiv \frac{m!}{j!(m-j)!}$ is firstly increasing, then hits its  maximum, then it becomes decreasing. The picture below represents $f_m$ for $m=3,...,9$.[image]

Now, take the functions

- $g$ such that $m\in \mathbb{N}\mapsto g(m)\equiv \max_{j\in \{0,...,m\}}f_m(j)$.
- $h$ such that $m\in \mathbb{N}\mapsto h(m)\equiv 2^{m}$.

**Question:** what is the growth rate in [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of $g$? what is the growth rate in Big O notation of $h$? How do they compare?

Comment: Note that $g(m) = \binom{m}{\lfloor m/2\rfloor}$. Do you know Stirling's formula?

Comment: Thanks: No, but I'm happy to study it if I understand where is needed here.

Comment: You get the asymptotic behaviour of $g$ if you use Stirling's formula for each of the factorials making up the central binomial coefficient. There's a lot of cancellation, and the final result is pretty nice. Tip: it's much nicer for even $m$, so for odd $m = 2k-1$ use $\binom{2k-1}{k-1} = \frac{1}{2}\binom{2k}{k}$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle \frac{m!}{j!(m-j)!}$ is commonly referred to as a binomial coefficient and usually writen as $\binom{m}{j}$.

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{m}{j}}{\binom{m}{j-1}} = \frac{m-j+1}{j}$, thus $\binom{m}{j}$ increases strictly so long as $$\frac{m-j+1}{j} > 1\iff m\geq 2j\iff \lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor\geq j$$

Thus $\displaystyle g(m)= \binom{m}{\lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor}$. If $m$ is even, write $m=2k$ and $\binom{m}{\lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor} = \binom{2k}{k}$. Going back to factorials, Stirling's estimate (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) or [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient)) yields $\displaystyle \binom{2k}{k}\sim \frac{2^{2k}}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$.

If $m$ is odd, write $m=2k+1$, so that $\binom{m}{\lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor} = \binom{2k+1}{k} = \binom{2k+1}{k+1}=\frac{2k+1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}$. Using the previous estimate, $\displaystyle \frac{2k+1}{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}\sim \frac{2^{2k+1}}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$.

Therefore $$g(m) \sim \frac{2^m}{\sqrt{\pi \lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor}}$$

Since $\displaystyle \lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor = \frac m2 +O(1)$, $\displaystyle \lfloor \frac m2 \rfloor \sim \frac m2$ thus

$$g(m) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{2^m}{\sqrt{m}} = o(h(m))$$

Comment: Thanks. What is the growth rate in Big O notation? How is compared to the growth rate of $h$?

Comment: @Tex $O$ notation is not precise enough to assess the growth rate of a sequence. For example $m+1=O(m^2)$, but the relevant asymptotic is $m+1\sim m$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks. What's the best way to write in math that the growth rate of $g$ is smaller than the growth rate of $h$?

Comment: $O$ does not imply "smaller": for example $m^2+m = O(m^2)$. "smaller" is usually denoted by using $o$ notation: $g(m)=o(h(m))\iff \frac{g(m)}{h(m)}\to 0$. This goes to say that $g$ is negligible in front of $h$.